# ruby-sdl-ffi how to define callback and pass it to AddTimer

Tags: ruby, callback, sdl, ffi

Im triying to use SDL timers, but i cant find documentation on how to pass or define the callback function to the method;

```
callback(:timer_cb, [ :uint32 ], :uint32)
sdl_func  :SetTimer, [ :uint32, :timer_cb ], :int

callback(:newtimer_cb, [ :uint32, :pointer ], :uint32)
sdl_func  :AddTimer, [:uint32, :newtimer_cb, :pointer], :pointer
```

I figured out it should go something like.. SDL::Addtimer(time, "here goes a proc?", "FFI::MemoryPointer" ?)

Any help or point to docs or examples would be apreciated.